# Downloading files in background with Python

Tags: python, web-applications, background

I have got a working web application in Python that downloads a file into the web server upon a user's request. This works fine for small file downloads but when the user requests a larger file, the connection times out. So, I think I need to process the download in the background but I'm not sure what tool is most suitable for this. Celery seems to be right but I don't really want it to be queued(the download must start immediately). What would you suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Timout duration is up to you, you could just make it longer.

Anyway there are plenty of flash or AJAX uploaders out there, nothing you can do only *server side* AFAIK

Comment: I should have been more clearer- the download happens from another site, not the user's computer. It is not uploading so AJAX uploaders are out of the question

Comment: @SamratManSingh: You should be more clear in the question itself.  Please **update** the question to include **all** of the details of your situation.